# Barban-Davenport-Halberstam without von Mangoldt weights

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

The Barban-Davenport-Halberstam theorem gives a bound for the average (in L_2 norm) difference between 
$\sum_{n\leq N: n\equiv a \mod q} \Lambda(n)$ and $N/\phi(q)$. It is obvious that a similar result should hold for the
difference between $\sum_{p\leq N: p\equiv a \mod q} 1$ (where $p$ ranges only across primes) and $\pi(N)/\phi(q)$. Does anybody know where in the literature a statement in that form can be found (so that it can be quoted without any further ado - the alternative is to spend some space in its derivation)?

Comment:  I don't know of any such cut and dried reference but I find dealing with von-Mangoldt easier than dealing with primes. 

Comment: Yes, that's why the von Mangoldt function was ever defined. At the same time, we sometimes have to deal with primes!

Comment: Well said Mukherjee!

Comment: This is obviously a cultural reference I am missing. At any rate, can we get back to the question?

Comment: Have you seen Theorem 17.5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski? I think that is all you need.

 

Comment: Thank you - I think it is just what was needed. How could I miss it?

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 17.5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski seems to do the job.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading - what exactly is Iwaniec-Kowalski?

Comment: It is the modern bible of analytic number theory. 

http://books.google.com/books?id=8i7wpzjSWrIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Iwaniec-Kowalski&source=bl&ots=GOKNmL0Au-&sig=3WgRL402_K33SpdhuE1dIj3NzqM&hl=en&ei=kqnHTJS0I8q3cNz79LEF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks. To save others the trouble of clicking through, it's Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski, Analytic Number Theory, American Mathematical Society Colloquium Publications Volume 53. 